# Google Authentication on different devices doesnt work while locally testing (Reactjs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-oauth

first of all, Google Authentication v.9 (signing in and registering) is working fine when I test it on my local (windows) laptop (the same as on which the nodejs server is running).

App is almost completely finished and ready for deployment so I wanted to test it on other devices too.
So, I used my iPad and iPhone and went to ip.address:3000 and there I got the opening page. But when I click on the 'Sign in with Google' thingie, there is no pop-up window. Only a blank new tab opens (accounts.google). Pop-up are allowed on both devices.

Is this normal behavior? Or did I do something wrong code-wise.
Then I checked again on my (local) windows laptop and everything works as it should.
But I noticed there is an error message in the console 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.postMessage call.'. Is this the reason why it's not working on ios devices? I been looking for hours and there seems to be no solution for this one (yet).

Would the same behavior show up when I deploy it on the www?

I know, a strange question. And I am fully aware that I might have done something wrong or forgotten something.
But I hope someone can help me.

edit:
this is the code I run

```
const { handleGoogle, loading, error } = useFetch('http://192.168.0.999:8800/login');


useEffect(() => {
    /* global google */
    if (window.google) {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            callback: handleGoogle
        });
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById('loginDiv'), {
                    theme: 'outline',
                    text: 'continue with',
                    shape: 'pill',
                    //size: 'small'
        })
    }
}, [handleGoogle]);
```

it works fine on my local machine. But as soon as I try it on iPad or iPhone, no pop up appears only a blank white screen. I think this one should be the one where I can choose which Google account to choose from. Refreshing this page ... stays blank. Safari, Chrome show the same behavior.
And this is the url of the blank tab that opens: https://accounts.google.com/gsi/xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&ux_mode=popup&ui_mode=card&asxxxxxxxxxxx192.168.0.999%3A3000

Comment: welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem working in other platforms.  I'm not familiar with react syntax but I suspect you are setting the callback URL with the following line...

```
const { handleGoogle, loading, error } = useFetch('http://192.168.0.999:8800/login');
```

I also suspect that the IP address is referencing your machine that everything works on.  You may want to try a localhost or 127.0.0.1 for iOS devices to see if you can at least see the phrase "callback received" on the iphone and ipad.  At that point, things will be working correctly. When you return to the app (whether that happens automatically for your or you need to manually switch back to the app), the authentication should be approved.

Comment: Thx for the reply but I dont think this is the problem. The ip address is the one from where my nodejs is running on and I can reach it from but ios devices.
the issue arises earlier with the Google Authentication screen not showing (nor as a popup, nor in the other tab).